# "Shall" at the end of a sentence

Tags: question-tags, shall-future

I hear people ending sentences in a question like:

*you didn't ...do you?*
*he is ... isn't he?*
*she should... shouldn't she?*

What about *shall*? Can I say: *I shall (do something), shall I*? or *I shall... shall I not*?

When can I end a sentence with *shall I*? Do I need to start the sentence with the negative of *shall* (what is it?)

Comment: Setting aside that "shall" is a bit archaic, not really a word people use a lot anymore, most people instead using "should" or "will" (in the UK where "shall" in the first person used to be commonly used instead of "will"), yes, "shall I not" is something you could say after "I shall" (e.g., "I shall, shall I not?").  Again, that sounds very old-fashioned, but it's not ungrammatical.  Also, be aware of the contraction "shan't" as a worthy substitute (e.g., "I shall, shan't I?").  Also, some people might instead say, "I shall, shall I?"

Comment: "Shall I pick you up at six?" is perfectly natural in all dialects. "Will I pick you up at six?" sounds Irish to me"!

Comment: Guy, could you list two or three examples, please?

Comment: In American English _shall_ is limited to two first-person question uses: singular, which is an offer to do something for the addressee: _Shall I turn it off?_ And plural, which is an invitation to the addressee to do something together with the speaker: _Shall we dance?_ Other than that, it doesn't really occur outside laws except when Americans try to sound formal and stuffy.

Comment: Let's go now, shall we? It is also the tag for let's, first person plural. Let's be nice, shall we? To me, it sounds educated but I won't say it to the gas station attendant.

Comment: BillJ's example is an excellent one because it really challenges what a lot of us think of "shall" as being uncommon or stilted in informal speech. I personally would use "Should I pick you up", but that's just me. "Will" sounds Irish to BillJ, any other word for someone else may sound not quite right. Lambie's example also is a good one, because there's no other word other than "shall" that would be so fitting at the end of those questions, ie. "can", "could", "should". Though you could argue that "Let's be civil, shall we?" may sound formal or smug, in my opinion it's neither necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use this at the end of a choice sentence.

> Will you eat the last triple chocolate brownie or **shall I**?

Comment: Well done. Mine and yours cohere, kinda.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's all play nice, shall we?**

**Let's have a drink now, shall we?**

**Tags can get tricky in English.**

I'm a pain, **aren't I?**

But, of course, we also have:
I'm a pain, am I not?

Answer (score 0):

Shall is a weird pick for end of sentence negation, as it is mostly used in a fate/higher power -ordains kind of way nowadays. 'I shall die tomorrow', ' nobody shall touch the body', etc. . '  - the negation as 'shall i not' is good, as the concatenated 'shan't i' does not express the negation as clearly (also compare don't/ do i not, won't/will i not,...).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the tag question at the end needs to flip the polarity by adding a *not* if the initial statement lacked it and by subtracting the negative if the initial statement had it.

So for example:

- I shall die tomorrow, **shan’t I**?
- I shall not pass this way again, **shall I**?

Those aren’t really in common use, no.